# Is that true about "Encapsulation" and "Abstraction "?

Tags: java, encapsulation, abstraction

Encapsulation is just hiding the internal mechanism of the program

Abstraction is providing a public interface from encapsulated program

is that true ??

Comment: Why is this question tagged `java`?

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Encapsulation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Abstraction

Answer (score 1):

**Encapsulation** is how you reduce tight coupling between components, by hiding their implementation details while exposing a consistent interface. Encapsulation means you can change how a unit performs its work without affecting the behaviour of all other units that use it.

**Abstraction** is the more general concept of simplifying or generalizing something. For a better explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)